# MR_deleteInContext throwing exception. Could anyone explain root cause of this? Below bold lines returns nil context which makes application to crash

Tags: magicalrecord

```
- (BOOL) MR_deleteInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    **NSManagedObject *inContext = [context existingObjectWithID:[self objectID] error:&error];**

    [MagicalRecord handleErrors:error];

    [context deleteObject:inContext];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I solved the problem. In above code "SELF" which is entity object seems to be from different context so does return Nil context which fails deleting the object. So make sure, you get the entity object from the context in which you are deleting the object.